# Core Animation cache

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

How do you clear a Core Animation cache programmatically if any. With time, my app's performance gets very slow and the profile instrument tells me it's because of Core Animation. I was hoping if it will be possible to refresh core animation in my app from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not a cache issue, even its if you mess up within this area you will have another issue, I suggest to run the profiler and check if you have a leak somewhere, make sure you are releasing all your ivars porperly, use
 `CGImageRelease(cgImage)`, `CGPathRelease(path)`, ..etc

plus take a look [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/03/block-retain-loop/) and [here also](http://www.think-in-g.net/ghawk/blog/2012/05/2-stories-about-memory-leak-in-objective-c/)